# How do I ensure that two model fields are unique together?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-5, unique-constraint

I have the following model:

```
public class tbMailingList
{
    public int ID { get; set; }

    [Display(Name = "Group")]
    public int tbGroupID { get; set; }

    [Display(Name = "Recipient")]
    public int tbRecipientID { get; set; }

    public virtual tbGroup tbGroup { get; set; }
    public virtual tbRecipient tbRecipient { get; set; }
}
```

How do I ensure that both tbGroupID and tbRecipientID are a unique pair using C# and MVC5?

A given pair (tbGroupID, tbRecipient) must be unique

- row 1 (1,1)
- row 2 (1,2)
- row 3 (2,1)
- row 4 (1,2) Not Allowed Duplicates 'row 2'

I have done a lot of searching, but no answers.

Comment: Are they supposed to be unique in some kind of ORM?

Comment: Unique is usually used when comparing and object to some other object or collection of objects. So Unique compared to what?

Comment: I've added an example.

Comment: @Chris Yes, I'm looking for something resembling the unique_together constraint that is available in django ... more info here: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/options/

Comment: I have edited your title. Please see, "[Should questions include “tags” in their titles?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/19190/)", where the consensus is "no, they should not".

Answer (score 0):

you can try to specify unique key like in db if you are using EF

```
[Key, Column(Order = 0)]
 public int ID { get; set; }
 [Key, Column(Order =1)]
 [Display(Name = "Group")]
 public int tbGroupID { get; set; }
```

Comment: I am wanting a unique key 'pair' where the pair is tbGroupID and tbRecipientID.

Comment: Well this will create a unique pair at least will not allow to have an object where two keys are not unique

Comment: The tbGroupID is not permitted to be unique on its' own.